# Black Screen when using Tiled in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

For the game I'm making I use Tiled to make and edit maps. However, these maps don't load in the sample I've made so far:

```
package com.bluezamx.magillion.screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FillViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.Viewport;
import com.bluezamx.magillion.Magillion;
import com.bluezamx.magillion.utils.Constants;

public class WorldScreen implements Screen {

    private Magillion game;
    private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    private Stage stage;

    //Tiled variables
    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer maprenderer;

    // Box2D variables
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debug;

    public WorldScreen (Magillion game) {
        this.game = game;
        gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("TestWorld.tmx");
        maprenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / Constants.PPM);

        gamePort = new FillViewport(Constants.WIDTH / Constants.PPM, Constants.HEIGHT / Constants.PPM, gameCam);
        gameCam.position.set((gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2), (gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2), 0);

        world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), true);
        debug = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        debug.SHAPE_STATIC.set(1, 0, 0, 1);

        for(MapObject object : map.getLayers().get(1).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
            Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();

            bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
            bdef.position.set(rect.getX() + rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getY() + rect.getHeight() / 2);

            body = world.createBody(bdef);

            shape.setAsBox(rect.getWidth() / 2, rect.getHeight() / 2);
            fdef.shape = shape;
            body.createFixture(fdef);
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void show() {}

    private void update(float dt) {
        handleInput(dt);

        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
        player.update(dt);

        gameCam.update();
        maprenderer.setView(gameCam);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float dt) {
        update(dt);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        debug.render(world, gameCam.combined);
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
        maprenderer.render();

        game.batch.begin();
        player.draw(game.batch);
        game.batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        map.dispose();
        maprenderer.dispose();
        world.dispose();
        debug.dispose();
    }
}
```

When I run my file (which automatically sets the game screen to this file), I only get a black screen. The map itself doesn't show. The map is 640 * 480 big and placed in the standard android/assets folder.

I tried running my map in other code I found online and it worked there. I couldn't figure out what's wrong with mine, however.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your viewport with device screen width and height.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
     // use true here to center the camera
     gamePort.update(width,height,false);
}
```

Take a look of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020908/3445320) answer, recently I added as solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your map is actually rendered, but simply your Viewport is out of map position.
Try using:

```
gamecam.setToOrtho(false, gamePort.getWorldWidth()/2, gamePort.getWorldHeight()/2);
```

instead of

```
gameCam.position.set((gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2), (gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2), 0);
```