# My Tiled map is not being rendered in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, tiled

I have spent the past couple of days trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Im trying to render a tile map (.tmx) in libgdx but it does not render and it just shows a red screen with no error. I have re-written the code a few times and  I always getting the same result.

my code:

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
TiledMap map;
TmxMapLoader loader;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
OrthographicCamera camera;

@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = loader.load("TiledMaps/TestMap.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render();

    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    map.dispose();
}
```

}

Can anybody find what is happening here I have the tmx file with the tilesheet in the TileMaps folder in the android assets folder.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set map size on Android using LibGdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018391/how-to-set-map-size-on-android-using-libgdx)

Comment: what is the value of tileWidth,tileHeight, mapWidth, mapHeight of your map?

Comment: I think you need to wrap `renderer.render()` inside `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`. You can see [here](https://github.com/haxpor/raceplant/blob/master/core/src/io/wasin/raceplant/states/Play.kt#L933-L963) similar to what you did over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're attempting something complex (map rendering) but encountering a simple problem (not rendering anything).

Have you got a simple program where you do have something rendering?  Built it up so you have a few hard coded tiles rendering?  Built it up a bit more to correctly read and display the first tile from the map? Before finally extending it further to read and display all the tiles, once you know the basics are working?

That's how I would tackle this problem.  Been programming for years, and just used the same process to get CreateProcess working in C++ on Windows.  Wasn't working within my code so I built an empty project that just runs CreateProcess on notepad.exe and tweaked things with answers from StackOverflow.com till I got it working, now it's about adding back in the other complications bit by bit so I'm not completely lost by taking on too much at once.

Comment: Im not too sure what you are saying but from what i could understand I should start by rendering just 1 tile then move on from there? If this is what you meant i have no idea how to do that using libgdx api and all the code i provided worked a few months ago. @Domarius

Comment: I'm pretty confident your problem isn't libgdx specific, it's more of a general problem solving issue.  Logic dictates if your code hasn't changed between then and now, that something else has, and you need to simply do trial and error to narrow down what that could be. 

What I'm telling you here is not the answer to the problem, but how to find the answers to problems, which is more important :)

If you are aiming to render an entire map but have no idea how to even render a single tile all by itself, this is a serious step you've skipped.  You need to learn the basics first.

Comment: I noticed libgdx has a forum, have you posted there?  But even more important than that, there should be tutorials on how to get something rendering on the screen, you should follow that, it'll probably have a crucial step in setting things up to render correctly that you've missed.

Comment: Im past getting things to render correctly i can get anything to render but not my tmx file and the code im using is the same code that worked before so i dont see how learning to render a single tile would help me, am i missing something?

Comment: Well, like I said, something has changed between then and now, and you have to break the problem down, eliminating all the things it can't be till you're left with something to work on.   So if you can certainly render something then the problem is somewhere between being able to render something and rendering a map.

Comment: Let's break it down - do you know if it's loading the map incorrectly, or if it's just not rendering it correctly? If you don't know which, you need to find out.  You need to test the loading by perhaps printing the numeric value of each tile (to the log output), or even simply the number of tiles, to see if it is indeed loading the data.

Comment: If that checks out, then the problem may be with the rendering.  In this case it will help to just get one tile rendering, and it may simplify things if you hard code the contents of "map" to be like, 1 or 2 tiles.  I think a TMX file is in XML format so it shouldn't be too difficult to type up something in the code.

Comment: I checked if everything was getting loaded and it was and it took a me a bit of testing to find out it was the maps i was using that were the problem not the code. Now to find out why my maps dont work anymore

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear it :) Good luck with the rest of the search.